# Change Asterix cat 240 stream data (xml) to radar image (visualize) using python or C++

Tags: python, numpy

I do have a stream of radar data cat 240 coming from SPX Radar Simulator and Asterix is successfully receiving the stream and parsing it. What I need is to visualizing radar data on my monitor as radar image. See the attachment.

I am trying to write a code in python to parse the cat 240 line by line output generated by Asterix, then use the "Data Item I240/050, Video Block Low Data Volume" data to construct my radar image, but no luck so far. I am open to any suggestions!

For three seconds, I get 6000 Data Block output from Asterix, and here is a sample output of Data Block from "asterix -i ip:ip:port" command for one record is:

```
"-------------------------
Data Block 1
Category: 240
Len: 1376

Data Record 1
Len: 1376
CRC: 3555AA95
Timestamp: 66896282

Item 010 : Data Source Identifier
[ 00 00 ]
System Area Code: 0
System Identification Code: 0

Item 000 : Message Type
[ 02 ]
Message Type: 2 (Video message)

Item 020 : Video Record Header
[ 0B E8 C3 56 ]
Message Sequence Identifier: 199803734

Item 041 : Video Header Femto
[ 2A 9A 2A B3 00 00 00 00 02 54 75 86 ]
Start azimuth of the cells group: 10906 (59.9084473 deg)
End azimuth of the cells group: 10931 (60.0457764 deg)
Starting range of the cells group, expressed in number of cells: 0
Video cell duration in femto-seconds: 39089542

Item 048 : Video Cells Resolution and Data Compression Indicator
[ 00 04 ]
Data Compression Indicator: 0 (No compression applied)
spares bit set to 0: 0
Bit resolution used for the coding of the amplitude of the video signal in every cell of a video group: 4 (High Resolution (coding length = 8 bits))

Item 049 : Video Octets and Video Cells Counters
[ 05 14 00 05 14 ]
Number of valid octets: 1300
Number of valid cells: 1300

Item 051 : Video Block Medium Data Volume
[ 15 05 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 2E 23 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 21 21 21 21 21 21 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 24 24 24 23 23 23 23 23 22 22 22 22 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 24 24 24 24 24 24 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 21 21 21 23 23 23 23 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 24 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 24 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ]
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 052E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E23262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 2626262626262626262626262626262625252525252525252525252525252525252525212121212121FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF252525252525252524242424242424242424242424242424242424252525252525252525252525252525252525252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525252525252525252525252525252323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232326262626262626262626262626262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626252525252525252525242424232323232322222222242424242424242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242323232323232323232323232323222222222222222525252525252525252525252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252524242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424242424242424242525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525252525252525252524242424242422222222222222222121212323232324242424242424242424242425252525252525252525252525252525252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262624252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262624262626262626262626262626262626262626262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626262626262626262626262626262525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424242424242424252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525252525252525252526262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262525252525252525252525252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525252525252525252525252424242424242424242424242424242424242525252525252525252525252525252525252626262626262626262626262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626262626262626262626262626262626262626262624242424242424242424242424242424242424242424242424262626262626262626262626262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626262626262626262626262626262626260000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Item 140 : Time Of Day
[ 82 A8 2E ]
Time Of Day: 8562734 (66896.3593750 s)
Data Block 2
Category: 240
Len: 780

Data Record 1
Len: 780
CRC: 61E68A4A
Timestamp: 66896282

Item 010 : Data Source Identifier
[ 00 00 ]
System Area Code: 0
System Identification Code: 0

Item 000 : Message Type
[ 02 ]
Message Type: 2 (Video message)

Item 020 : Video Record Header
[ 0B E8 C3 57 ]
Message Sequence Identifier: 199803735

Item 041 : Video Header Femto
[ 2A 9A 2A B3 00 00 05 14 02 54 75 86 ]
Start azimuth of the cells group: 10906 (59.9084473 deg)
End azimuth of the cells group: 10931 (60.0457764 deg)
Starting range of the cells group, expressed in number of cells: 1300
Video cell duration in femto-seconds: 39089542

Item 048 : Video Cells Resolution and Data Compression Indicator
[ 00 04 ]
Data Compression Indicator: 0 (No compression applied)
spares bit set to 0: 0
Bit resolution used for the coding of the amplitude of the video signal in every cell of a video group: 4 (High Resolution (coding length = 8 bits))

Item 049 : Video Octets and Video Cells Counters
[ 02 EC 00 02 EC ]
Number of valid octets: 748
Number of valid cells: 748

Item 050 : Video Block Low Data Volume
[ BB 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 24 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 ]
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 23232323
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 23232323
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 23232323
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 23232323
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252524
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242422
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 22222222
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 22222223
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 23232323
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 23232326
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26232323
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 23232323
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 23232525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262622
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 22222222
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 22222222
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252526
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 25252525
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 24242424
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626
Video signal amplitude of the cells in the group: 26262626

Item 140 : Time Of Day
[ 82 A8 2E ]
Time Of Day: 8562734 (66896.3593750 s)
"

selection_009

file:///home/julian/Desktop/Selection_009.png
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SPx scan converter to convert the ASTERIX CAT-240 radar stream into a bitmap or image for display. The scan converter has a full C++ API for receipt, processing, scan conversion and display of radar video.

Comment: I already figured it out by reading the Item 051: Video Block Medium Data Volume data [ 15 05 2E ...] and convert each two hex 15 , 05, 2E .... and convert it to float then store it N*M matrix, and continue same think for the next coming message until I have a full image. Finally take linear polar to convert it to radar space. then done.

Comment: @user3765968: how do you figure out the size of the matrix (i.e. dimensions M and N)?